# Cannot Ping Server From Specific IP Address

Tags: firewall, ping

I have two virtual machines (Web Server and DB Server), which are connected to each other using local network.

The issue I am having is that I cannot ping DB Server from the Web Server, though I have added Web Server's IP address to the Firewall of DB Server as an inbound rule. Also, when I switch the rule in Firewall to allow all connection instead of the specific IP it's works.

Could you please suggest what can prevent pinging the DB server from the Web Server considering setting I have applied. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to allow ICMP in the firewall.

Comment: I did, same problem. Work only when all IPs are allowed. If I specify one it does not work.

Comment: @EmilGurbanov IPv4 and/or IPv6? Try enabling ICMP for the specific IP using both versions.

Comment: I actually found my mistake, I was adding the the specific IP address to both Local IP Address fiend and the Remote IP. So I just removed the local one, and it helped. But anyway thanks for you answers :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I specified the IP address to the both Local IP Address field and the Remote IP Field (My Rule Properties -> Scope).

Once I removed the local one, it worked.